# Declare a set of arrays with dynamic dimension

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA I would like to declare a set of arrays. Says X01, X02, .., X99
Each with different dimensions

I tried with Dim X(1 to 99). However, it seems difficult to set dimension for each later.

Is there any efficiency way to declare arrays in this situation?
Example:

```
X01: size (5,6)
X02: size (2,3)
X03: size (1,9)
etc
```

Comment: Is there any pattern to the differing dimensions? Otherwise your normal declarations are the most "efficient" way. Note that this may be an X-Y problem - what are you actually going to do with these arrays and why do you need 99?

Comment: A part of my work require VBA now.
Previously I worked with Matlab this is not a problem. However, it seems like in VBA everything need to be declare and it is causing frustration for me :(
There is a hacking-alternative way is combine string on Excel then copy & paste into VBA as a Dim in normal way. But that way to declare variables is kind of strange :/ when looking at the code

Comment: Can you explain why you need so many arrays though? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can freely declare arrays in runtime. Google for the `Redim` command.

Comment: @BigBen's comments/questions are relevant. The 'why' is important as just trying to recreate what Matlab does might not be the best way to implement in VBA. Fundamentally you're try to create an unevenly populated 3 key (assuming 99 may not be the limit) dataset ... I've put some options down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ArraysOfArrays()

    ' Option #1 ... individual, explicit definitions
    Dim X01(5, 6)
    Dim X02(6, 3)
    ' etc

    ' Option 2 ... a three dimension array
    Dim Y(99, 10, 10)
    Y(0, 0, 0) = "A"
    Y(1, 5, 6) = "B"
    ' etc

    ' Option 3 ... an array of different arrays
    Dim Tmp
    Dim Z(99)
    ReDim Tmp(5, 6): Z(0) = Tmp
    ReDim Tmp(6, 3): Z(1) = Tmp
    ' etc

    ' Option 4
    ' ... create a table with three keys in some form of database

    ' Option 5
    ' ... use a worksheet, a dictionary or one of the myriad of other options  :)

End Sub
```